# Ionic 4 - Dismiss or close Modal on platform hardware back button android

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4

In ionic 4, on hardware back button press I want to close or dismiss any modal that will be present.
I have used the below given code, here the condition "if(modal) { modal.dismiss(); }" always get satisfied even if previous modal are dismissed

```
constructor(private platform: Platform, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {
this.initializeapp();
}
initializeapp() {
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(1, async () => {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.getTop();
    if (modal) {
        modal.dismiss();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Got one solution: I have set the priority to 0 i.e. this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(0, async () => {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.getTop();
    if (modal) {
        modal.dismiss();
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging around and Ionic registers a custom event `ionBackButton` for handling the hardware back button press:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/hardware-back-button.ts#L20

And the overlay code that manages all overlays in Ionic handles this `ionBackButton` event by dismissing the topmost overlay:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/utils/overlays.ts#L66

So what is your code trying to achieve?

It seems that it only does this when `backdropDismiss` is also set to true:

```
if (lastOverlay && lastOverlay.backdropDismiss) {
```

Which I assume means that it's classed as an optional/low-grade overlay, rather than simulating a modal.

Comment: On first hardware back button I have to check if any modal is open, if any modal is open then close that modal, if no modal is open then navigate one page back.

Comment: That's the default behaviour of Ionic 4 though isn't it? If it's not what you are experiencing then your overlays are not being set with `backdropDismiss`. The overlay system covers all types of overlays in Ionic. It seems that they use the `backdropDismiss` to discern if its an important overlay that shouldn't just be dismissed with the back button. If you are displaying unimportant overlays just ensure that the `backdropDismiss` is set so the hardware back button can close it.